# Angular variable is not refreshing (not displayed correctly in template)

Tags: angular, data-binding, ionic2, angular-services, angular-components

There are 2 components : `graph`, `node`
And 1 service: `nodesmanager`

`nodesmanager` is injected in `graph`

When the `graph` component detects a mouse click event, the injected service `nodesmanager` create a new node `n` by calling a function `AddNode`, call `n.setPos (22,44)`, and add `n` to a list of nodes `nodes`.

`setPos` should change 2 variables of `node`: `posX` and `posY`.

Then the template `node.html` should "echo" posX : `{{posX}}`

**But the problem is `{{posX}}` is not displaying the value of posX changed after `setPos`, It is not showing anything. It is considering `posX` to be undefined.**

> nodesmanager.service.ts:

```
@Input() nodes: NodeComponent [] = [] ;
constructor() { }
  
AddNode (x: number, y: number): void {
    let n = new NodeComponent ();
    n.SetPos(22,44);
    this.nodes.push (n);
}
```

> node.ts:

```
@Input()  posX: number;
@Input()  posY: number;

constructor(){}

SetPos (_posX: number, _posY: number): void{
    this.posX = _posX;
    this.posY = _posY;
    
}

ngOnInit() {}
```

> node.html (template):

```
<div>
    p: {{posX}}
</div>
```

> graph.ts:

```
constructor(public nodesManager: NodesManagerService) { }
ngOnInit() {}
  
MouseClicked (event: MouseEvent) : void {
    this.nodesManager.AddNode(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}
```

> graph.html (template):

```
<div class="graph" (click) = "MouseClicked($event)">
    <div *ngIf="nodesManager.nodes">
        <div *ngFor = "let node of nodesManager.nodes">
            <app-node></app-node>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove SetPos from the NodeComponent class

Change the nodesmanager service to just hold data

```
public nodes: any[] = [] ;
constructor() { }
  
AddNode (x: number, y: number): void {
    this.nodes.push ({x, y});
}
```

Change your template

```
<div class="graph" (click)="MouseClicked($event)">
    <div *ngIf="nodesManager.nodes">
        <div *ngFor="let node of nodesManager.nodes">
            <app-node [posX]="node.x" [posy]="node.y"></app-node>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem. Thank you

Comment: add a console.log inside the SetPos method to see what it's getting. When you say you're not getting anything, are you at least seeing the "p: " in the output?

Comment: Also, if that's the full signature of the NodeComponent class, I feel like you can simplify it massively by just having a constructor that takes the two properties and defined them as public.  you could then remove the SetPos method and the two inputs.

Comment: 1- Yes the letter "p" is printed in the browser. 2- doing `console.log(this.posX)` in the `setPos` function prints the right value of `posX` (22) in the console. But the problem remains in the tempale, it only prints "p: " like said in 1-

Comment: having the constructor of `NodeComponent` taking the two properties, creates a problem when creating a new `NodeComponent` using it's template in the `graph.html` (When doing `<app-node></app-node>`). I couldn't seem to figure out how to create a component that takes parameters in its constructor, using it's template.

Comment: Should the constructor of  `nodeComponent` take the 2 parameters ?

Comment: no.  in fact, you can remove the constructor completely and the ngOnit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219770/discussion-between-eeah-and-the-james).